# Auto login by Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make one Jquery script which help me to login in website by just one click.

E.g

I want to make auto login for gmail 
For than i write below Jquery Script

```
jQuery("#username").val("my UserName");
jQuery("#password").val("****");
jQuery("#submit").submit();
```

here

(#)username is id of username input box on login  page.

(#)password is id of password input box on login  page.

(#)submit is id of login button login  page.

and this Jquery add in my browser bookmark.
like this way

```
javascript:document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:81/kayako.js'></script>");
```

Now i want is i just open "mail.gmail.com" ( gmail is taken for just an exmple. ) and click on bookmark than it should be auto fill user name and password and also get autologin to gmail.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible due to the same-origin policy. Why not use a password safe or the built-in browser functions?

Comment: @Marvin 
I just want to make auto-login for my personal  laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like that:

```
document.getElementById("Email").value = "{{YOUR EMAIL}}";
document.getElementById("next").click();
setTimeout( function() {
   document.getElementById("Passwd").value = "{{PASSWORD}}";
   document.getElementById("signIn").click();
}, 1000);
```

because GMAIL login form work different now... you need to type the email, then click on Next and then type your password and click Sign In

(you can add this code to your bookmark with "javascript:" before)

Comment: no work for me :-( when i press on bookmark than page is going to Blank and then nothing happen. i must have to refresh this page.

Comment: Are you sure you bookmarked this:

javascript:document.getElementById("Email").value = "{{YOUR EMAIL}}"; document.getElementById("next").click(); setTimeout( function() { document.getElementById("Passwd").value = "{{PASSWORD}}"; document.getElementById("signIn").click(); }, 1000);

and after that, open gmail and click on the bookmart?

Comment: Go my mistake thank you :-) +1 and Accept your answer.i was just mistake with on syntax.

Comment: thank you. i'll edit the code in the next few hours trying to remove the setTimeout and do more elegant way (like wait until the 'Passwd' element create and then execute the rest of the code)

Comment: i will surely wait for it.